# Building V8 from source

Tags: javascript, shell, ubuntu, command-line, v8

Recently I've tried to build V8 JavaScript engine from source using *gm* with the help of the [documentation](https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn#gm), in order to use [d8](https://v8.dev/docs/d8) locally; but when I run `gm x64.release` command, It raises below exception.

```
# mkdir -p out/x64.release
# echo > out/x64.release/args.gn << EOF
is_component_build = false
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
use_goma = false
goma_dir = "None"
v8_enable_backtrace = true
v8_enable_disassembler = true
v8_enable_object_print = true
v8_enable_verify_heap = true
EOF
# gn gen out/x64.release
Done. Made 144 targets from 87 files in 443ms
# autoninja -C out/x64.release d8
b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.973835+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m original error: no such package\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.973974+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m \r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974037+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m goroutine 28:\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974094+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #0 go.chromium.org/luci/cipd/client/cipd/client.go:1690 - cipd.(*clientImpl).humanErr()\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974155+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #1 go.chromium.org/luci/cipd/client/cipd/client.go:744 - cipd.(*clientImpl).ResolveVersion()\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974226+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #2 go.chromium.org/luci/cipd/client/cipd/resolver.go:176 - cipd.(*Resolver).resolveVersion.func1()\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:1'b'1:53.974284+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #3 go.chromium.org/luci/common/sync/promise/promise.go:84 - promise.(*Promise).runGen()\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974339+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #4 runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 - runtime.goexit()\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974416+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m \r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974463+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m goroutine 27:\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974520+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m From frame 0 to 0, the following wr'b'appers were found:\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974571+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m   internal reason: MultiError 1/1: following first non-nil error.\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974626+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m \r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974678+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #0 go.chromium.org/luci/cipd/client/cipd/ensure/file.go:255 - ensure.(*File).Resolve.func1.1()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974732+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m   reason: failed to resolve infra/python/wheels/psutil/linux-amd64_cp32_abi3@version:5.6.2 (line 0)\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974787+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m \r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974840+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #1 go.chromium.org/luci/common/sync/parallel/runner.go:51 - parallel.(*WorkItem).execute()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974894+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #2 go.chromium.org/luci/common/sync/parallel/runner.go:149 - parallel.(*Runner).dispatchLoopBody.func2()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.974975+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #3 runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 - runtime.goexit()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975032+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m \r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975083+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m goroutine 1:\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975134+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #0 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/config.go:183 - venv.(*Config).makeEnv()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975188+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m   reason: failed to resolve packages\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975250+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m \r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975305+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #1 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:163 - venv.With()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975364+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #2 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/run.go:62 - vpython.Run()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975416+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #3 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:320 - application.(*application).mainImpl()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975470+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #4 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:406 - application.(*Config).Main.func1()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975522+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #5 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/support.go:46 - application.run()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975762+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #6 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:405 - application.(*Config).Main()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975834+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #7 vpython/main.go:106 - main.mainImpl()\r\n\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975884+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #8 vpython/main.go:112 - main.main()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975937+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #9 runtime/proc.go:203 - runtime.main()\r\n'b'\x1b[31m[E2020-03-07T11:11:53.975997+03:30 10007 0 annotate.go:241]\x1b[0m #10 runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 - runtime.goexit()\r\n'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/dev/gm.py", line 420, in <module>
    sys.exit(Main(sys.argv))
  File "tools/dev/gm.py", line 409, in Main
    return_code += configs[c].Build()
  File "tools/dev/gm.py", line 282, in Build
    (path, targets))
  File "tools/dev/gm.py", line 190, in _CallWithOutput
    return p.returncode, "".join(output)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

It is worth mentioning I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 as my operating system. I don't know what's wrong with it and how can I solve it!

Any response would be appreciated...

**Edit**: When I run the command using `python2` (I mean `python2 tools/dev/gm.py x64.release`), it causes some other issues like below

```
# autoninja -C out/x64.release d8
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767248+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] original error: no such package
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767304+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] 
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767335+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] goroutine 50:
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767361+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #0 go.chromium.org/luci/cipd/client/cipd/client.go:1690 - cipd.(*clientImpl).humanErr()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767395+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #1 go.chromium.org/luci/cipd/client/cipd/client.go:744 - cipd.(*clientImpl).ResolveVersion()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767426+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #2 go.chromium.org/luci/cipd/client/cipd/resolver.go:176 - cipd.(*Resolver).resolveVersion.func1()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767457+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #3 go.chromium.org/luci/common/sync/promise/promise.go:84 - promise.(*Promise).runGen()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767488+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #4 runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 - runtime.goexit()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767517+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] 
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767542+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] goroutine 49:
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767569+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] From frame 0 to 0, the following wrappers were found:
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767596+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241]   internal reason: MultiError 1/1: following first non-nil error.
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767624+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] 
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767649+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #0 go.chromium.org/luci/cipd/client/cipd/ensure/file.go:255 - ensure.(*File).Resolve.func1.1()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767680+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241]   reason: failed to resolve infra/python/wheels/psutil/linux-amd64_cp32_abi3@version:5.6.2 (line 0)
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767711+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] 
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767736+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #1 go.chromium.org/luci/common/sync/parallel/runner.go:51 - parallel.(*WorkItem).execute()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767767+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #2 go.chromium.org/luci/common/sync/parallel/runner.go:149 - parallel.(*Runner).dispatchLoopBody.func2()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767795+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #3 runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 - runtime.goexit()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767821+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] 
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767852+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] goroutine 1:
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767884+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #0 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/config.go:183 - venv.(*Config).makeEnv()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767918+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241]   reason: failed to resolve packages
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767947+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] 
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767968+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #1 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:163 - venv.With()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.767994+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #2 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/run.go:62 - vpython.Run()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.768022+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #3 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:320 - application.(*application).mainImpl()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.768047+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #4 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:406 - application.(*Config).Main.func1()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.768074+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #5 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/support.go:46 - application.run()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.768108+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #6 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:405 - application.(*Config).Main()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.768147+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #7 vpython/main.go:106 - main.mainImpl()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.768176+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #8 vpython/main.go:112 - main.main()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.768207+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #9 runtime/proc.go:203 - runtime.main()
[E2020-03-08T06:20:51.768241+03:30 14549 0 annotate.go:241] #10 runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 - runtime.goexit()
```

Comment: Eventually I managed to do it by change the Python default version in Ubuntu using the `update-alternatives` to version `python2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I realized, building V8 is not compatible with Python 3 yet and there were lots of issues when I tried building it using Python 3. Finally I changed the default version of Python in my OS (Ubuntu 18.04) to Python 2 and It worked like a charm.

At first I set the Python 2 as an alternative for Python:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 1
```

Then I selected `python2` as a default version of Python using the below command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Answer (score 1):

`gm.py` needs a minor fix to be compatible with Python 3. I have a patch lying around somewhere, but haven't yet gotten around to getting it landed...

In the meantime, you can run it in Python 2 manually:

```
python2 tools/dev/gm.py
```

If you have no `python2` command, then you'll have to install the corresponding package for your distribution.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried to running it using `python2` but it cause some other issues. So let me update my question based on new issues.